# ERB код в slim формате

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, slim-lang

Впервые использую `Slim`. И сразу проблемка. Как в Slim написать такой код?

```
<li><%= current_user.name%> <%= current_user.last_name.first.capitalize%></li><br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Slim можно интерполировать строки с помощью `#{}`

То есть будет так:

```
li= "#{current_user.name} #{current_user.last_name.first.capitalize}"   
br/
```

Или так:

```
li
  | #{current_user.name} #{current_user.last_name.first.capitalize}    
br/
```

P.S. А вообще, для вывода всяческих ФИО лучше использовать декоратор, так как часто придется копировать `#{current_user.name} #{current_user.last_name.first.capitalize}`

Comment: Спасибо! работает, и нащет декоратора учту:)